# Fastest way to get count of rows of strings containing a substring in python between two data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have two data frames, 1 has words and the other one has the text. I want to get the count of all the rows containing the word in the first data frame.

Word =

```
ID   | Word
------------
1    | Introduction
2    | database
3    | country 
4    | search
```

Text  =

```
ID   | Text
------------
1    | Introduction to python
2    | sql is a database
3    | Introduction to python in our country
4    | search for a python teacher in our country
```

What I want as final output is

```
ID   | Word  |  Count
---------------------
1    | Introduction  | 2
2    | database  | 1
3    | country  |  1
4    | search  |  2
```

I have 200000 rows in the word df and 55000 rows in the text (length of each text is around 2000 words) df. It takes approx 76 hours to complete the entire process with below code

'''

```
def docCount(docdf, worddf):
    final_dict = {}
    for i in tqdm(worddf.itertuples()):
        docdf["Count"] = docdf.Text.str.contains(i[2])
        temp_dict = {i[2]: docdf.Count.sum()}
        final_dict = dict(Counter(final_dict)+Counter(temp_dict))
    return final_dict
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

#### Here is simple solution

```
world_count = pd.DataFrame(
    {'words': Word['Word'].tolist(),
     'count': [Text['Text'].str.contains(w).sum() for w in words],
    }).rename_axis('ID')
```

**Output:**

```
world_count.head()

'''
           words  count
ID                     
0   Introduction      2
1       database      1
2        country      2
3         search      1
'''
```

**Step by step solution:**

```
# Convert column to list
words = Word['Word'].tolist()

# Get the count
count = [Text['Text'].str.contains(w).sum() for w in words]

world_count = pd.DataFrame(
    {'words': words,
     'count': count,
    }).rename_axis('ID')
```

Tip:

I would suggest you to convert to lower case so that you won't miss any count due to upper/lower case

```
import re
import pandas as pd

world_count = pd.DataFrame(
    {'words': Word['Word'].str.lower().str.strip().tolist(),
     'count': [Text['Text'].str.contains(w,flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True).sum() for w in words],
    }).rename_axis('ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example to speed things up:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Word':['Introduction', 'database', 'country', 'search']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['Introduction to python', 'sql is a database', 'Introduction to python in our country', 'search for a python teacher in our country']})

tmp = pd.DataFrame(df2['Text'].str.split().explode()).set_index('Text').assign(c=1)
tmp = tmp.groupby(tmp.index)['c'].sum()
print( df1.merge(tmp, left_on='Word', right_on=tmp.index) )
```

Prints:

```
           Word  c
0  Introduction  2
1      database  1
2       country  2
3        search  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for Series of words:

```
s = df2['Text'].str.split().explode()
#oldier pandas versions
#s = df2['Text'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
```

Then filter only matched values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df1.join(s[s.isin(df1['Word'])].value_counts().rename('Count'), on='Word')
print (df1)
           Word  Count
0  Introduction      2
1      database      1
2       country      2
3        search      1
```